# Search the word from given text and split into variable

Tags: asp.net

i have a ckeditor text and i want to search the particular word from the text and use a the information for calculation.

for example whenever Background-color rgb(r,g,b) encountered I want to split this  3 variable into r,g b another variable and convert into hex Code . please help me out....

Comment: You'll need to describe your problem some more. What's the relationship with your WYSIWYG editor and a PDF? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank u for ur help. I got the ans little bit r&d and i got it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string HtmlText = "style='background-color:rgb(191, 191, 191); style='background-color:rgb(196, 189, 151); style='background-color:rgb(217, 217, 217);";
            Console.WriteLine(HtmlText);

            Regex backgroundReplacer = new Regex(@"style='background-color:rgb\((?<red>\d+),\s(?<green>\d+),\s(?<blue>\d+)\);");            
            string replaced = backgroundReplacer.Replace(HtmlText, new MatchEvaluator(Program.BackgroundToBgColor ));

            Console.WriteLine(replaced);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string BackgroundToBgColor(Match m)
        {
            int red = int.Parse(m.Groups["red"].Value);
            int green = int.Parse(m.Groups["green"].Value);
            int blue = int.Parse(m.Groups["blue"].Value);

            return string.Format("bgcolor='#{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}' style='", red, green, blue);
        }
    }
```